# Divisive clustering from scratch

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'm programming divisive (top-down) clustering from scratch. In divisive clustering we start at the top with all examples (variables) in one cluster. The cluster is than split recursively until each example is in its singleton cluster.

I use Pearson's correlation coefficient as a measure for splitting clusters. Pasted below is my initial attempt. I read the data and compute matrix of correlation coefficient.

Now we need to split first cluster according to minimal value of the correlation coefficient. Any idea how to proceed? Any pointers and suggestions are welcome.

```
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt

# Read data from GitHub
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nico/collectiveintelligence-book/master/blogdata.txt', sep = '\t', index_col = 0)
data = df.values.tolist()
data = data[1:10]

# Define correlation coefficient
def pearson(v1, v2):
  # Simple sums
  sum1 = sum(v1)
  sum2 = sum(v2)
  # Sums of the squares
  sum1Sq = sum([pow(v, 2) for v in v1])
  sum2Sq = sum([pow(v, 2) for v in v2]) 
  # Sum of the products
  pSum=sum([v1[i] * v2[i] for i in range(len(v1))])
  # Calculate r (Pearson score)
  num = pSum - (sum1 * sum2 / len(v1))
  den = sqrt((sum1Sq - pow(sum1,2) / len(v1)) * (sum2Sq - pow(sum2, 2) / len(v1)))
  if den == 0: return 0
  return num / den


# Dict for distances
dist={}
min_dist = pearson(data[0], data[0])
# Loop over upper triangle of data matrix
for i in range(len(data)):
  for j in range(i + 1, len(data)):
     # Compute distance for each pair
     dist_curr = pearson(data[i], data[j])
     # Store distance in dict
     dist[(i, j)] = dist_curr
     # Store min distance
     if dist_curr < min_dist:
       min_dist = dist_curr
```